# Se puede forzar a la aplicacion, tomar foto con flash y otro sin flash

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación del cual use la cámara para detectar enfermedades o problemas en las encias, empleo opencv para el proceso de deteccion, el problema es capturar 2 fotos diferentes, es decir uno con flash y otro sin flash y para que no resulta problematico para el usuario comun

Answer (score 2):

Para tomar la foto con flash, usa el método [**setFlashMode()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFlashMode(java.lang.String)) (funciona desde API 5) con [FLASH_MODE_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_ON) :

```
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

después de tomar la primera foto con flash, usa el mismo método pero ahora con
[FLASH_MODE_OFF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_OFF) para tomar la foto sin flash :

```
parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
```

Te sugiero validar primeramente si tu cámara soporta el flash:

```
    if (parameters.getFlashMode()==null) {
       //No se tiene flash
    } else {
    //se tiene flash
   }
```

Comment: gracias, me sirvio mucho.

Comment: Una consulta, se puede tomar 3 capturas seguidas con solo un toque, modo rafaga que tiene las camaras.